# function that returns a value from column b when specifying a value from column a

Tags: r

[image: example data]

Hi I would like to create a function where I type the value of `exampledataframe$X1` and it will return the corresponding value `exampledataframe$X2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `==`

```
exampledataframe$X2[exampledataframe$X1=="A"]
```

As a function

```
fun1 <- function(data, Var1, Var2, val){
           data[[Var2]][data[[Var1]]==val]
   }

fun1(exampledataframe, "X1", "X2", "B")
#[1] "4"
```

#### data

```
exampledataframe <- data.frame(X1= c("A", 1, "B", 2, "C"), 
               X2= c(3, "D", 4, "F", 5), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```